# Automatically resize equilibrium constants in superscripts with chemmacros

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros, chemformula

Using the `chemmacros` commands `\K...` and `\p...`, equilibrium constants and p functions don't get resized when written as superscripts. For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{[\ch{B^-}]}{[\ch{HB}]}=10^{\pH-\pKa}\mbox{.}
\]
\end{document
```

becomes

[image]

with too big superscripts.

Comment: I ran `texdoc chemmacros` and searched for  both `math` and `size`, but nothing I could find seemed to have an answer ;-(

Comment: Need to check but this looks like a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the `acid-base` module. Here is a fix:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\chemmacros_if_compatibility:nnT {<=} {5.8b}
  {
    \cs_set_protected:Npn \chemmacros_p:n #1
      {
        \group_begin:
          \chemmacros_text:n
            {
              \chemmacros_p_style:n {p}
              \ensuremath {#1}
            }
        \group_end:
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[ 10^{pH}=10^{\pH} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll send the updated version to CTAN in a few days…